# How do we use comprehension here

Tags: python

I have the following multi-loop situation:

```
notify=dict()
for m in messages:
    fields=list()
    for g in groups:
        fields.append(func(g,m))
    notify[m.name]=fields
return notify
```

Is there a way to write the below as a comprehension or map ,that would look better(hopefully perform better too)

Comment: What's the point of `result` here, to just take on the last value in the nested loop? Should it be `result.append`?

Comment: Modified the code to mention the intention too

Comment: Do you mean to create a new `notify` every loop?

Comment: my bad - moved the definition outside the loop now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you really mean notify to accumulate all the results

```
return {m.name: [func(g, m) for g in groups] for m in messages}
```

Comment: This is very interesting.Is there a way to exclude cases where func() return a None.I would not be needing those cases to be added into the dict.

Comment: @IUnknown, Do you mean when all the `func()` for a particular `m` return None, or just to suppress it from the individual lists?

Answer (score 2):

```
from itertools import product
results = [func(g,m) for m,g in product(messages,groups)]
```

EDIT

I think you may actually want a dict of dicts, not a dict of lists:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import product
results = defaultdict(dict)
for m,g in product(messages,groups):
    results[m.name][g] = func(g,m)
```

Or borrowing from gnibbler:

```
return {m.name: {g:func(g,m) for g in groups} for m in messages}
```

Now you can just use `results[msgname][groupname]` to get the value of `func(g,m)`.

Comment: Very interesting - but am not able to fit this into the current scenario.I guess it cannot be made any concise than what I have put up then.

Comment: If `func` is very expensive, you could lazily init this structure by memoizing `func`. Then you would only compute the values actually needed instead of exhaustively computing func for all messagename-group combinations.

Answer (score 1):

Don't you want the dictionary to be returned? As follows (assuming m has field name)

```
notify={m.name:[func(g,m) for g in groups] for m in messages}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not using comprehensions, but simplifies your code a bit.

```
from collections import defaultdict

def foo(messages, groups):

    notify=defaultdict(list)
    for m in messages:
        for g in groups:
            notify[m.name].append(func(g,m))
    return notify
```